# Run out of virtual memory after added to triple physical RAM and change SQL Server memory option?

Tags: memory, sql-server, windows-server, performance-tuning

Recently, we added some physical RAM to our server which running SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, the total memory was changed from 64GB to 192GB.

And we tuned the memory option of SQL Server by changing the 'min server memory' from 16GB to 64GB, and the 'max server memory' from 48GB to 128GB.

And the pagefile of Windows Server 2008 R2 is left unchanged with 64GB.

But after two days later, Windows Server reported run out of virtual memory, some 'Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition' events can be found in EventLogs. We cannot connected via remote desktop client, and cannot launch mmc or notepad application even though operating from console, only Explorer and task manager can be opened. at that time, about 50% physical memory was used.

And now, we change 'min server memory' back to 16GB, the server runs without any resource exhaustion detector events, but the physical RAM usage was always lower than 64GB.

Please give us some direction. thanks.

Comment: *"And the pagefile of Windows Server 2008 R2 is left unchanged with 64GB."* -- Why? After tripling the installed RAM and quadrupling parameters, leaving this pagefile unchanged is a mistake.  The ratio of 'min server memory' to pagefile size went from 4:1 to 1:1.  As soon as the pagefile is full, no more pages can be swapped out, and allocation of new virtual memory is then blocked, i.e. you *"run out of virtual memory"*.